# Upload script won't upload

Tags: php, file-upload

My upload script won't upload. No errors displayed.

This is the script I use:

```
$target = "includes/pdf_files/attesten/".$id.".pdf";
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))
```

but nothing gets upload, this is my formfield:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?" method="POST">
    <table class="pop_up" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" style="background-color: #e7e7e9" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kies pdf file</td>
        <td><input name="uploaded" type="file" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true,this.form.submit();" value="<?php echo $lang['form_submit']; ?>" /> <input type="reset" value="<?php echo $lang['form_cancel']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

I'm using an local testserver (Xammp), $id is set.

Comment: Doest your <form> tag include multipart ? Did you inspect your params to see if there is anything in the $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name']

Comment: <form method="post" id="new_document" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="new_document" action="/documents">

Comment: @Rafal, I have added the form to my question.

Comment: To test, set your target to an absolute path (to a writable folder by the server) and check that the file gets there, your form works, I check the output and the file is stored in $_FILES.

Comment: Try take a look at the w3schools explanation; http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @Thew: No linking to [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) please. That example in particular is exploitable because it writes to unverified filenames.

Answer (score 1):

This is a debug question, hence I give you a debug answer.

First thing you should try is `print_r($_FILES);` to see if the expected variable names are present. It will also show you any occoured `["error"]` which your current code doesn't check about.

Then the most common error is a lack of write permissions. If you don't get an error, then raise the error_reporting level and enable display_errors in php.ini. open_basedir restrictions are the second most common error (though less likely in your example).

See also the 'Common pitfalls for file uploads' section in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php